# How to change model location for fixture in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model, fixture

I am writing a custom plugin for the awesome framework CakePHP, called: `TableTool`.

My plugin has a default folder structure, created by `cake bake`:

```
-app   (some subfolders omitted)
--plugin  
---TableTool
----Config
----Console
----Controller
-----TableToolAppController.php
----Lib
----Model
-----TableToolAppModel.php
                   <= old location of the model
----Test
-----Case
------View
-------Helper
--------TableToolHelperTest.php
------Fixture
--------PostFixtureTest.php
-----TestApp        <= manually added
------Model
-------Post.php     <= new location of the model
----Vendor
----View
-----Helper
------TableToolHelper.php
```

The plugin is a helper-tool without a specific model. For test purposes a use a Model: `Post`. It is located in `app\plugin\TableTool\Model\Post.php` (old location) and works fine in my test case.
Because the model Post.php is only for test purposes I have tried to change the location to: `app\plugin\TableTool\Test\TestApp\Model\Post`.
After the change my test case started with complaining: Model `Post` could not be found. That wasn`t a surprise. The fixture needs a folder location for the model. I have tried the following:

```
 class PostFixture extends CakeTestFixture {

    public $import = array('model' => 'TableTool.Model/Post', 'records' => true, 'connection' => 'test_tooltable');

    public function init() {
        App::build(array('TableTool.Model' => array(APP . 'Plugin' . DS . 'TableTool' . DS . 'Test' . DS . 'TestApp' . DS . 'Model' . DS)));
        parent::init();
    }

}
```

In the `lib\cake\Test` folder, I have seen a `test_app`.... I have look around for examples in it, but I didn't found the solution....

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a Plugin that uses a model purely for testing purposes: https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload

In particular, see this file: https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload/blob/master/Test/Case/Model/Behavior/UploadTest.php where the test model class (having barely any code) is just declared up the top of the test file. Note that the model extends `CakeTestModel` rather than `AppModel`

Then the fixture is pretty simple: https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload/blob/master/Test/Fixture/UploadFixture.php

It just contains the line:

```
public $name = 'Upload';
```

Comment: `public $name = 'Upload';` can be totally omitted here, though :)